# Почему composer не может найти bower-asset'ы?

Tags: composer, bower

**1.** Создал две папки:

- `composer-bower-asset-0-0-1`;
- `composer-bower-asset-1-0-0`.

**2.** В каждую положил следующий `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "composer-bower-asset-<version>",
  "authors": [
    "John Doe <john.doe@example.com>"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

**3.** Также закинул `main.js` со следующим содержанием:

```
console.log('composer-bower-asset-<version>');
```

**4.** Запушил пакеты в соответствующие репозитории:

- https://bitbucket.org/w3lifer/composer-bower-asset-0-0-1
- https://bitbucket.org/w3lifer/composer-bower-asset-1-0-0

С тегами `0.0.1` и `1.0.0` соответственно.

**5.** Зарегистрировал их:

```
bower register composer-bower-asset-0-0-1 https://bitbucket.org/w3lifer/composer-bower-asset-0-0-1
bower register composer-bower-asset-1-0-0 https://bitbucket.org/w3lifer/composer-bower-asset-1-0-0
```

**6.** Очистил кэш:

```
bower cache clean
composer clearcache
```

**7.** Установил `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

**8.** Попробовал установить пакеты с помощью `bower`'а:

```
bower install composer-bower-asset-0-0-1
bower install composer-bower-asset-1-0-0
```

**Всё OK.** Стали соответствующие версии.

**9.** Попробовал с помощью `composer`'а:

```
composer require bower-asset/composer-bower-asset-0-0-1
composer require bower-asset/composer-bower-asset-1-0-0
```

В обоих случаях:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>
> Could not find package bower-asset/composer-bower-asset-<version> at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

---

**Почему так?**